# infinispan cluster two nodes configuration 5.3.Final

Tags: caching, configuration, cluster-computing, infinispan

We want to create a cluster with two nodes, we have followed  the steps of https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Infinispan+Server, we use the configuration file of  standalone/configuration/clustered-two-nodes.xml. We have changed some ports like 8080, 9999, 4447 and 127.0.0.1 to the IP of the machine. We tried it, but it didn't work. 
Is the best configuration to work with a cluster of two nodes?? 
Is there any step that we didn't see?? 
I saw several threads and it seem to be the correct way, but we tried differents configuration and it doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: Do you start cluster of 2 different machines? (probably yes) Or 2 servers on 1 machines but with different ports? Do you use tcp or udp in you configurations. Can you post your altered config files somewhere. It could potentially be some minor issue. Also, I've seen some question here on stack overflow, where people were dealing with the same issue. Did you try to look at these? Thx

Answer (score 0):

We start cluster of 2 different machines, we use tcp in the configurations. I have followed server questions but we didn't get solution to our problems.
These are our changes:
IP.IP.IP.IP = our ip.

```
   
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:1.2" default-stack="${jboss.default.jgroups.stack:tcp}">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:IP.IP.IP.IP}"/>
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:IP.IP.IP.IP}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management"                         port="${jboss.management.native.port:19999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9991}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8081"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4448"/>
```

Comment: We have got the solution. Thank you by your interest.

Comment: Can you tell us about the solution? Thanks